# Can comments be added as markers in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to make a plug-in that adds comments as markers to the Javascript editor (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor).

I can see from the tutorials that Eclipse does allow to attach markers to IResources:

```
<extension
         id="org.eclipse.test.marker"
         name="org.eclipse.test.marker"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
      <super
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker">
      </super>
      <persistent
            value="true">
      </persistent>
</extension>
```

And that these markers can also be attached to annotations, which adds an appearance to them (org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification ).

This works fine for highlighting and changing the appearance of text in the editor.
My questions is, is there any kind of marker that also adds text comments to the editor without actually modifying the document?

As an alternative, I was considering adding the comments programmatically and attaching markers to them, but there are multiple drawbacks in this approach. I was wondering if Eclipse would have an automated alternative:

```
    public void addCommentMarker(String commentText, int Offset) throws CoreException {

        //Get the active editor
        IEditorPart editorPart=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
        if (!(editorPart instanceof AbstractTextEditor))
                return;
        ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)editorPart;

        //Add comment programmatically to the file: 
        IDocumentProvider dp = editor.getDocumentProvider();
        IDocument doc = dp.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
        try {
            doc.replace(Offset, 0, "//"+commentText); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Create a marker to monitor the new comment: 
        IFile file=getFileFromEditorInput(editor.getEditorInput());
        IMarker m=file.createMarker(IMarker.TEXT);

        //Marker begins when the comment starts:
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, Offset);

        //Marker ends when the comment ends:
        m.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, Offset+commentText.length()+2);
    }
```

As mentioned by Nitind, my intention is to create the tag-like functionality. For example in the following screenshot, to be able to add tags programatically with a constant's value (//20).

[Sample desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqm2E.png)

Since I am new to Eclipse, I am not sure if Eclipse provides an alternative for managing this tags programatically.

Comment: You have this a little backwards--markers never modify the file, but they are often created in response to what is in the file. Are you referring to the Task Tags functionality, where the contents of the file on disk are scanned to create and remove Task markers automatically? In that case text from the file is extracted to fill in the Task marker that gets created. You should read up on https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html

Comment: Thanks Nitind... I have modified the post with the actual desired behavior.... As you mention, my intention is to manage tags programmatically.  I wonder if Eclipse provides an alternative for doing this.